# How to calculate factor score, lower and upper bounds for CFA model when there is NAs in the data

Tags: r, r-lavaan

How can we calculate factor score, and the lower and upper bounds (or confidence intervals) for CFA model when there is NAs in the data:

Here is an example:

```
ID = 1:500
states = rep(c("TS", "NE", "AR", "MO", "WA"),times = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100))
schools = randomNames::randomNames(500) ## 5 first last names separated by a space
Gender = rep(c("male", "female"),times = c(180,320))

item1 = runif(500, min=.05, max =.95);  ind1 <- which(item1 %in% sample(item1, 55)); item1[ind1]<-NA
item2 = runif(500, min=.66, max=1);  ind2 <- which(item2 %in% sample(item2, 200)); item2[ind2]<-NA
item3 = runif(500, min=.05, max=.85);  ind3 <- which(item3 %in% sample(item3, 155)); item3[ind3]<-NA
item4 = runif(500, min=.40, max=1);  ind4 <- which(item4 %in% sample(item4, 150)); item4[ind4]<-NA
item5 = runif(500, min=0, max=.99);  ind5 <- which(item5 %in% sample(item5, 100)); item5[ind5]<-NA

df = data.frame(ID, states, schools, Gender, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)


syntaxScale = " 
Satisfaction =~ item1 + item2 + item3 + item4 + item5

Satisfaction ~~ 1*Satisfaction;
Satisfaction ~ 0;
"

Fit_Scale = lavaan::cfa(model = syntaxScale, data = df, estimator = "MLR", std.lv = FALSE)

summary(Fit_Scale, fit.measures = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using Full Information Maximum Likelihood helps when you have missing data (under certain assumptions of course). More information [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51006/full-information-maximum-likelihood-for-missing-data-in-r).

```
Fit_Scale = lavaan::cfa(model = syntaxScale, data = df, estimator = "MLR", std.lv = FALSE,missing="fiml")
```

For the estimation of factor score, you can use lavPredict().

```
sem_pred <- lavPredict(Fit_Scale,type="lv") %>% 
  data.frame()

hist(sem_pred$Satisfaction,main = "Satisfaction",xlab = "Factor score")
```

[image: Distribution of factor score]

Comment: Thank you, @jvargh7 - the factor score function worked. Is there a way to calculate the upper and lower bounds/ confidence intervals of the factor scores?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding missings, if you look within `lavaan` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaan/lavaan.pdf), you will see:

> If "listwise", cases with missing values are removed listwise from the
> data frame. If "direct" or "ml" or "fiml" and the estimator is maximum
> likelihood, an EM algorithm is used to estimate the unrestricted
> covariance matrix (and mean vector). If "pairwise", pairwise deletion
> is used. If "default", the value is set depending on the estimator and
> the mimic option.

As so, you can use either "direct" or "ml" or "fiml" in the `missing` argument:

```r
Fit_Scale <- lavaan::cfa(model = syntaxScale, data = df, estimator = "MLR", std.lv = FALSE, missing = "ml")
```

Regarding, factor scores (it works even if you did pairwise deletion):

```r
idx <- lavInspect(Fit_Scale , "case.idx")

fscores <- lavPredict(Fit_Scale )

# loop over factors
for (fs in colnames(fscores)) {
df[idx, fs] <- fscores[ , fs]
}
```

Confidence intervals for all parameters:

```r
parameterestimates(Fit_Scale, ci=T)
```